# Liquibase Preconditions of Unique Constraints (indexExists) Doesn't Work for HSQLDB Databases?

Tags: hsqldb, liquibase

When I upgrade an existing HSQLDB database (*the database does not contain the 2 Liquibase control tables - **databasechangelog** and **databasechangeloglock***) using a Liquibase script (*displayed as follows*), an error occurs reporting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: object name already exists: SOME_TABLE_UK in statement [ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.SOME_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT SOME_TABLE_UK UNIQUE (COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4)]`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <property name="TYPE_AS_ID" value="VARCHAR2(36 BYTE)" dbms="oracle" />
    <property name="TYPE_AS_ID" value="VARCHAR(36)" dbms="postgresql" />
    <property name="TYPE_AS_ID" value="VARCHAR(36)" dbms="hsqldb" />

    <property name="TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT" value="VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)" dbms="oracle" />
    <property name="TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT" value="TEXT" dbms="postgresql" />
    <property name="TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT" value="VARCHAR(255)" dbms="hsqldb" />

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="1">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="SOME_TABLE" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="SOME_TABLE">
            <column name="COLUMN_1" type="${TYPE_AS_ID}">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="COLUMN_2" type="${TYPE_AS_ID}" />
            <column name="COLUMN_3" type="${TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT}" />
            <column name="COLUMN_4" type="${TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT}" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="2">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE">
            <column name="COLUMN_1" type="${TYPE_AS_ID}">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="COLUMN_2" type="${TYPE_AS_NORMAL_TEXT}" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="3">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <primaryKeyExists tableName="SOME_TABLE" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <addPrimaryKey constraintName="SOME_TABLE_PK" tableName="SOME_TABLE" columnNames="COLUMN_1" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="4">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <primaryKeyExists tableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <addPrimaryKey constraintName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE_PK" tableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE" columnNames="COLUMN_1" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="5">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyName="SOME_TABLE_FK" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="SOME_TABLE_FK" baseTableName="SOME_TABLE" baseColumnNames="COLUMN_2" referencedTableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE" referencedColumnNames="COLUMN_1" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="RESTRICT" onUpdate="RESTRICT" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="RayChen" id="6">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <indexExists indexName="SOME_TABLE_UK" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <addUniqueConstraint constraintName="SOME_TABLE_UK" tableName="SOME_TABLE" columnNames="COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

But I have already added a **not indexExists** precondition in the changeset to create that **SOME_TABLE_UK** unique key as follows, why does the above error occur?

```
<changeSet author="RayChen" id="6">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <indexExists indexName="SOME_TABLE_UK" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <addUniqueConstraint constraintName="SOME_TABLE_UK" tableName="SOME_TABLE" columnNames="COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4" />
</changeSet>
```

What makes me more confused is, the Liquibase script works well without errors when the database is Oracle or PostgreSQL (*the above change set #6 will be skipped due to the **not indexExists** precondition*), and similar code works well without errors for primary keys and foreign keys.

Comment: The index that supports the unique constraint is not named `SOME_TABLE_UK` in HSQLDB - it gets a generated name. e.g. `SYS_IDX_SOME_TABLE_UK_10120`. You need a "sql precondition" that checks if the unique constraint is defined, not the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the reply. I also doubted that, but when I performed the SQL statement `ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT SOME_TABLE_UK;` in HSQLDB Database Manager, it succeeded; while I performed the SQL statement `ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_IDX_SOME_TABLE_UK_15356;`, it failed (_SYS_IDX_SOME_TABLE_UK_15356 is the display name in HSQLDB Database Manager for the unique key SOME_TABLE_UK_).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I want to use a SQL precondition to check whether a unique key exists, could you give me an example about how to write it? Thanks.

Comment: The _constraint_ is indeed named `SOME_TABLE_UK` but the _index_ is not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right! I changed that statement from `<indexExists indexName="SOME_TABLE_UK" />` to `<indexExists indexName="SYS_IDX_SOME_TABLE_UK_15356" />` and it works in HSQLDB. Thanks! But, I just tested, that name differs every time when it is generated by HSQLDB (_now is SYS_IDX_SOME_TABLE_UK_15691 after I cleared the database and re-run the Liquibase script_), so I cannot rely on the name in the code. Could we have another approach to write a Unique Key Exist precondition?

Comment: Change the CREATE TABLE statement in existing db and give the UNIQUE constraint a name, you can then use the name in your script. `CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE(.... CONSTRAINT SOME_TABLE_UK UNIQUE(COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4))`

Answer (score 4):

There is another approach to this issue. You can manage your own precontions by using the sql system objects. (I'm not sure if this is the correct HSQLDB syntax)
.

```
<changeSet author="RayChen" id="6">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
             <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE 'SOME_TABLE_UK%'</sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <addUniqueConstraint constraintName="SOME_TABLE_UK" tableName="SOME_TABLE" columnNames="COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4" />
<changeSet/>
```

Comment: I got " liquibase.precondition.core.SqlPrecondition@4b2b3da0 : ERROR: relation "sys.objects" does not exist". Liquibase 4.23.1.

Comment: What dbms are you using? 
The idea is to list all database objects.

Comment: Ah Postgres. It doesn't work for Postgres.

Comment: The example above has an MSSQL syntax I'm not familiar with Postgres but after a quick review, by checking the pg_constraint table you must be able to list your constraints. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535831/how-to-get-column-name-from-pg-constraint

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase starts supporting uniqueconstraint check on precondition since 4.9.0

```
uniqueConstraintExists  
Checks for the existence of unique constraints before running the update. (since Liquibase 4.9.0)

<preConditions>
<uniqueConstraintExists constraintName="uq_constraint_name" tableName="test_table"/>
</preConditions>

<preConditions>
<uniqueConstraintExists tableName="test_table" columnNames="first_name, last_name"/>
</preConditions>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue with mysql and liquibase version 4.18.0 using yaml

my script was

```
 - changeSet:
     id: unique_constraint_id
     author: User (generated)
     preConditions:
       - onFail: MARK_RAN
       - not:
           uniqueConstraintExists:
             tableName: x_table
             constraintName: unique_constraint_on_x_table
     changes:
         - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames: id, lang
            constraintName: unique_constraint_on_x_table
            tableName: x_table
```

I have changed it as @KingDSL said with fixs some names
and it worked

```
- changeSet:
      id: unique_constraint_id
      author: User (generated)
      preConditions:
        - onFail: MARK_RAN
        - sqlCheck:
            expectedResult: 0
            sql: "select count(*) from information_schema.table_constraints where CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%unique_constraint_on_x_table%'"
      changes:
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames: id, lang
            constraintName: unique_constraint_on_x_table
            tableName: x_table
```