# How to get column name from pg_constraint

Tags: postgresql, psql

I need to get a list of constraints from db and match them with columns they are related to
For this task I'm going to use pg_constraint. Here is the query that I use

```
 select conrelid::regclass AS table_from, conname, pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
from   pg_constraint c
join   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
 where conrelid::regclass::text = 'test' order by contype;
```

As you can see I'm interested in constraints for table called **test**
Here is the output

```
table_from |    conname     | pg_get_constraintdef 
------------+----------------+----------------------
 test       | test_age_check | CHECK ((age > 0))
```

But I want to get a column name for this constraint using query above (In this case column is **age**). According to [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/catalog-pg-constraint.html) `Column constraints are not treated specially`. But maybe there are some ways I can use to retrieve column name from **pg_constraint** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pg_constrint.conkey` holds an array of the columns ordinals in the table. You can use them to join `pg_attribute`. Here the ordinal is in the column `attnum`.

```
SELECT c.conrelid::regclass AS table_from,
       c.conname,
       pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid),
       a.attname
       FROM pg_constraint c
            INNER JOIN pg_namespace n
                       ON n.oid = c.connamespace
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.conkey) ak(k)
            INNER JOIN pg_attribute a
                       ON a.attrelid = c.conrelid
                          AND a.attnum = ak.k
       WHERE c.conrelid::regclass::text = 'test'
       ORDER BY c.contype;
```